# How to use input hidden in JSF?

Tags: jsf

How do I get the jsf form where the user enters their data, so you can save me the method returns:

`#{actorController.pagination.getItemsCount ()}`

in the class attribute: `# {beanXML.persona.actorId}`

(using the hidden input so that the user does not see it)

Because try with the following syntax and it does not work:

```
<h:inputHidden id="#{beanXML.persona.actorId}#" value="{actorController.pagination.getItemsCount()}">
```

Comment: Because try with the following syntax and it does not work: 

  <h:inputHidden id="#{beanXML.persona.actorId}#" value="{actorController.pagination.getItemsCount()}">

Comment: Add # in value and remove second # from id: `<h:inputHidden id="#{beanXML.persona.actorId}" value="#{actorController.pagination.getItemsCount()}">`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Why to use a hidden field when you can use different actions for your, uhm, actions?

Comment: Vasil Lukach: The syntax was copied wrong, I wanted put that you wrote 

The question is: has the inputhidden other attributes that can be used for what I do, you keep what brings me the method: # {actorController.pagination.getItemsCount () 
  in the class attribute: 
# {BeanXML.persona.actorId} 

For the user to NOT see it. Or there is another option instead of inputhidden? 

Thanks for answer.
Greetings

Comment: Luigi Mendoza: lo que quiero hacer es que no aparezca en la vista la clave foranea para que el usuario llene su valor, sino que yo se lo asigne mediante un metodo .Por eso es que queria usar el inputhidden para ello. El problema es que no encontre los atributos adecuados de esta etiqueta para guardar el resultado que me devuelve el metodo: # {actorController.pagination.getItemsCount ()} ,en la clase: #{beanXML.persona.actorId}.